# Find the direction in which the directional derivative of f(x,y), at the point (x,y)=(0,4), has a value of 1.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

f(x,y) = 9*e^(-0.5*x*y)

Find the direction in which the directional derivative of f(x,y), at the point (x,y)=(0,4), has a value of 1.  Please input your answer as a column vector.

When trying to solve i got:
fx ---> (-18)
fy ---> (0)
So does this mean 1 = (-18,0)*(x,y)
--->   1=-18x+0y
--->   x=1/-18
---> (-1/18)
(  0  )
As a column vector shown above

Or
does this mean 1 = (-18,0)*(cos(theta),Sin(theta))
---> 1 = -18 Cos(theta)
---> Theta = 93.2 degrees
Do i give my answer in degrees or radians and how would i show my answer as a column vector

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x,y)=9e^{-\frac{1}{2}xy}$ so clearly
\begin{equation*} \nabla f(x,y)=\langle f_{x}(x,y),f_{y}(x,y)\rangle = \left\langle 9e^{-\frac{1}{2}xy}\left(-\frac{1}{2}y\right),9e^{-\frac{1}{2}xy}\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)\right\rangle = -\frac{9}{2}\langle ye^{-\frac{1}{2}xy}, xe^{-\frac{1}{2}xy}\rangle\end{equation*}
and it follows that
\begin{equation*} \nabla f(0,4)=-\frac{9}{2}\langle 4e^{0},0\rangle =\langle -18,0\rangle \end{equation*}
and finally, you need to find the direction (i.e. unit vector $\vec{u}=\langle u_{1},u_{2}\rangle$ such that $\nabla f(0,4)\cdot\vec{u}=1$. Then,
\begin{equation*}1=\nabla f(0,4)\cdot\vec{u}=\langle -18,0\rangle\cdot\langle u_{1},u_{2}\rangle = -18u_{1} \end{equation*}
and this implies that $u_{1}=-\frac{1}{18}$ so ultimately, $\vec{u}=\left\langle-\frac{1}{18},u_{2}\right\rangle$ will work for the choice of $u_{2}$ that makes $\vec{u}$ a unit vector. As column vector per your question, this is $\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{18} \\ u_{2} \end{pmatrix}$.